# How to check if a port is in use using powershell

Tags: powershell, tcp, port

Is there a way in powershell to check if a given port is in use or not?

Comment: have you tried searching for "powershell port" ?

Comment: Do you mean TCP/IP Port?

Comment: Just searching over google, found [this](http://dthomo.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/powershell-to-check-tcp-port-is-open/). may b it help.

Answer (score 43):

Use [Get-NetTCPConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=win10-ps)

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | where Localport -eq 5000 | select Localport,OwningProcess

Localport OwningProcess
--------- -------------
    5000          1684
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PowerShell Core v6 and above use [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection)

```
>Test-Connection localhost -TcpPort 80
True
```

Comment: If you are using PowerShell Core v6 and above

Answer (score 1):

Following the other answers, once you run `Get-NetTCPConnection | where Localport -eq 5000 | select Localport,OwningProcess` you can check which process/application is using the port by running [Get-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.2)

```
Get-Process -Id <OwningProcess>
```

Comment: How would this call find details about a port?

Comment: Once you get the OwningProcess with this `Get-NetTCPConnection | where Localport -eq 5000 | select Localport,OwningProcess` you then run `Get-Process -Id <OwningProcess>` and you know wich application or process is using the port so you can kill that process from the task manager

Comment: Yes i mean exactly You need both to get the answer in this better detail, i would recommend updating Your solution to  contain both perhaps even using an array variable to store the result and look the other thing up to flex Your script muscles and surely be better and more complete than the other suggestions in themselves to totally justify why yours is a viable and relevant addition to the other suggestion(s)

Answer (score 0):

You could just roll it into one:

`Get-NetTCPConnection | where Localport -eq 5000| Select-Object Localport,@{'Name' = 'ProcessName';'Expression'={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).Name}}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).